# Jira post function - get current issue ID / Key

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I'm writing post function that will change custom fields values on transition. I need to get issue Id or Key. Problem is that I can't access any data through `Issue issue;` becouse object is empty...

Comment: add your problem code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
(...)
private MutableIssue mutableIssue;

public void execute(Map transientVars, Map args, PropertySet ps) throws WorkflowException {

     MutableIssue issue = (MutableIssue) getIssue(transientVars);
     System.out.println("Issue Id: " + issue.getId() + "\n"); 
}
(...)
```

Above code allows to get issue object from Jira post-function *execute* method level.